# Disable landscape mode in compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

How to disable landscape mode for a composable function? I want to show the composable in portrait mode always.

PS: Cannot set it in manifest file for the activity since I want this behaviour for one composable only and not others in the activity.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this with `DisposableEffect` + activity `requestedOrientation`.

```
@Composable
fun LockScreenOrientation(orientation: Int) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    DisposableEffect(Unit) {
        val activity = context.findActivity() ?: return@DisposableEffect onDispose {}
        val originalOrientation = activity.requestedOrientation
        activity.requestedOrientation = orientation
        onDispose {
            // restore original orientation when view disappears
            activity.requestedOrientation = originalOrientation
        }
    }
}

fun Context.findActivity(): Activity? = when (this) {
    is Activity -> this
    is ContextWrapper -> baseContext.findActivity()
    else -> null
}
```

Usage:

```
@Composable
fun Screen() {
    LockScreenOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE)
}
```